# Creating a descriptive table

Tags: descriptive-statistics, tables

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to report categorical and continuous data in one table.  I want to create a descriptive table summarizing some of the categorical and continuous data from the 3 treatment groups I had.

Comment: Take a look at what the [summary.formula](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/HmiscSummaryFormulaFunction) function in [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) provides for the R language. I believe this might be a good start if you want to use other statistical packages.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine you want want table with 3 major rows, one for each treatment.  Then in the columns you would define the variable you want to describe, be it continuous or categorical.  Then for each cell (which you can subdivide with some sort of structure if you need to), you'll provide the summary method that makes the most sense to you.  It is difficult to picture without knowing what kind of categorical data you have.  Moreover, in practice, the way you choose to present it will vary a lot on the specifics.  For example, what is the best way for you to present your categorical data?  Lists of counts?  Modes?

Comment: The way you described the table is how I envision it.  The way I plan to present the categorical data is through counts.  I was hoping to present the continuous data as an average.  I am doing this in SPSS.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah.  Well for the implementation specifics in SPSS, I have no idea.  I think what you'll probably want to do is to build your table manually in your word processing software using a Courier New (or other fixed width font) so that things line up the way you want.  If you have space, please don't just provide an average.  If the variable can be assumed to have anything like a normal distribution you should also provide either the standard deviation or the standard deviation of the mean.

Comment: @Amanda I agree with drknexus that providing mean alone is not very informative. [Here](http://imgur.com/I1EHWaA) is an idea of what the `summary.formula` function might give with two treatment groups and a mix of continuous and categorical variables (Source: Frank Harrell, `rreport` package, http://bit.ly/TkD7WU).